# Cannot add S3 bucket notification for lambda with LocalStack and Python boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, localstack

I am trying to launch an AWS lambda function when a `s3:ObjectCreated` event occur on LocalStack.

However I have the following error and I struggle to find why I do I have it:

```
An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the PutBucketNotificationConfiguration operation: Unable to validate the following destination configurations
```

Here is my Python code:

```py
import json

import boto3

print("save script started")
# Initialize a session using LocalStack
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id='test',
    aws_secret_access_key='test',
    region_name='eu-west-3',
)

# Create S3 and Lambda clients
s3_client = session.client('s3', endpoint_url='http://localhost:4566')
lambda_client = session.client('lambda', endpoint_url='http://localhost:4566')
iam_client = session.client('iam', endpoint_url='http://localhost:4566')


try:
    policy = iam_client.get_policy(PolicyArn='arn:aws:iam::000000000000:policy/s3-access')
    print("Policy already exists.")
    print(policy)
except iam_client.exceptions.NoSuchEntityException:
    print("Policy does not exist.")
    policy_document = {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["s3:GetObject"],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::input/*"
        }
    ]
    }

    iam_client.create_policy(
        PolicyName='s3-access',
        PolicyDocument=json.dumps(policy_document)
    )
except:
    print("An error occurred.")

try:
    role = iam_client.get_role(RoleName='execution_role')
    print("Role already exists.")
    print(role)
except iam_client.exceptions.NoSuchEntityException:
    print("Role does not exist.")
    assume_role_policy_document = {
        "Version":"2012-10-17",
        "Statement":[
            {
                "Effect":"Allow",
                "Principal":{"Service":"lambda.amazonaws.com"},
                "Action":"sts:AssumeRole"
            }
        ]
    }
    iam_client.create_role(
        RoleName='execution_role',
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument=json.dumps(assume_role_policy_document)
    )
except:
    print("An error occurred.")


iam_client.attach_role_policy(
    RoleName='execution_role',
    PolicyArn='arn:aws:iam::000000000000:policy/s3-access'
)



try:
    s3_client.head_bucket(Bucket='input')
    print(f"Bucket {'input'} exists.")
except s3_client.exceptions.NoSuchBucket:
    print(f"Bucket {'input'} does not exist.")

s3_client.upload_file('/tmp/my-lambda-function.zip', 'input', 'my-lambda-function.zip')

# Create a Lambda function
try:
    lambda_client.get_function(FunctionName='save')
    print("Function already exists.")
except: 
    lambda_client.create_function(
    FunctionName='save',
    Runtime='python3.10',
    Role='arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/execution_role',
    Handler='lambda_function.lambda_handler',
    Code={'S3Bucket': 'input', 'S3Key': 'my-lambda-function.zip'},
  )
finally:
    print("Adding permission to Lambda function...")
    lambda_client.add_permission(
        FunctionName='save',
        StatementId='s3-trigger-permission',
        Action='lambda:InvokeFunction',
        Principal='s3.amazonaws.com',
        SourceArn='arn:aws:s3:::input'
    )
    
    print("Adding bucket notification configuration...")
    try:
        s3_client.put_bucket_notification_configuration(
            Bucket='input',
            NotificationConfiguration={
                'LambdaFunctionConfigurations': [
                    {
                        'LambdaFunctionArn': 'arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-3:000000000000:function:save',
                        'Events': ['s3:ObjectCreated:*'],
                    },
                ],
            },
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

The `my-lambda-function.zip` is stored in the s3 bucket

I am pretty new to AWS so I may miss something

Comment: The error messages says "Unable to validate the following destination configurations". Is there any more to the error message? What are the following destination configurations?

Comment: No, unfortunately, even in LocalStack docker in Debug mode I do not have more precise error